# ActiveAdmin with schemas (multi-tenancy app)

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've installed ActiveAdmin on my multi-tenant app (using schemas with Apartment gem).
Accounts are in the default 'public' schema and attached users are in subdomains schemas.

When logging into ActiveAdmin, I am using the 'public' schema so I can access the Account table, but the User table is empty because there are no users in the 'public' schema.

Is there a way to list all users from all schemas at once ? Or as an alternative, to have a pull-down menu filter in ActiveAdmin to select one specific schema/subdomain which would then list all users for this schema/subdomain ?

Here's my ApplicationController to give some idea of how the app is handling the multi-schema tables.

Thanks for any ideas :)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :load_schema, :authenticate_user!
private
  def load_schema
   Apartment::Database.switch('public')
   return unless request.subdomain.present?

   if current_account
     Apartment::Database.switch(current_account.subdomain)
   else
     redirect_to root_url(subdomain: false)
   end
 end
 def current_account
   @current_account ||= Account.find_by(subdomain: request.subdomain)
 end
  helper_method :current_account
```

Comment: *Is there a way to list all users from all schemas at once*. Only with table inheritance, and that has other effects you may not want. Create a view that is a `UNION ALL` of all schemas. This is one of the reasons why schema-based multi-tenancy is less than ideal.

Comment: Any luck getting this working?  I am in the same boat.